# What's the best way to implement status change restrictions

Tags: mysql, node.js, restriction

I have a backend application in node and a mysql database.

Suppose I have these two tables:

**Entity**

| id | name | fk_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 1 |
| 2 | World | 2 |
| 3 | Bread | 3 |

**Status**

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

I want to implement a restriction to not allow status change from A to C.

Status A can only become B. B can only become C. C can become both A and B

- A -> B
- B -> C
- C -> A|B

Should I implement this restriction directly in the backend of my application *(using some if statements I guess)* or should I implement it in some "mysql way"? *(I can't see how I would do this btw)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to handle the warning shown in the example in your code, it wouöld be that much work, to implement the restrctions.

But the mysql way would always garantee, that such a updatee would happen, independent from the front end

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Entity
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(20), `fk_status` int)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Entity
>     (`id`, `name`, `fk_status`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Hello', 1),
>     (2, 'World', 2),
>     (3, 'Bread', 3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER teststatus BEFORE UPDATE ON Entity
> FOR EACH row
> BEGIN
> IF OLD.fk_status = 1 AND NEw.fk_status <> 2 THEN
>     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NOt AlLOWED';
> ELSEIF OLD.fk_status = 2 AND NEw.fk_status <> 3 THEN
>     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NOt AlLOWED';
>
> END IF;
>
> ENd
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Entity SET `name` = CONCAT( `name`,1) WHERE `id` = 3
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Entity SET `name` = CONCAT( `name`,1),fk_status = 3 WHERE `id` = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> NOt AlLOWED
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Entity SET `name` = CONCAT( `name`,1),fk_status = 1 WHERE `id` = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> NOt AlLOWED
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Entity
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name   | fk_status
> -: | :----- | --------:
>  1 | Hello  |         1
>  2 | World  |         2
>  3 | Bread1 |         3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d56c8e1ff16f26de308c64d166361682)*

Comment: This solution worked for me, thank you!! Just adding: I also created a table to store the possibilities of status changes (id,actual_status_id,status_allowed_id) and I use this to decide if the change should be allowed or denied